# Combining 4 Piezo Discs into One Signal

Tags: signal-routing

I want to work with 4 Piezo microphone discs, and would like to join the wires of them as one single signal together. Is this possible, and how can I combine 4 couples of those black/red wires of the Piezo discs to make one audio signal out of them?
Any helps is very appreciated.

Comment: Migrating to Electrical Engineering, as this is about connecting electrical components together.

Answer (score 2):

Simply mix the signals: add a resistor (say 1kOhm) in the red line from each piezo. You might want to experiment with the value of the resistors.

Answer (score 1):

A little more information would be helpful. What is the physical arrangement of the microphones? Combining them may form an array which will alter the beampattern. What sort of application is this for?

**Parallel connection**
If the mics are in an array receiving the same sound field the sensitivity will be unchanged (ignoring directivity index) and the impedance will be reduced 4 times. Polarity is important: join like colors.

**Series connection**
If the mics are in an array receiving the same sound field the sensitivity will increase 4 times (ignoring directivity index) and the impedance will increase 4 times. Polarity is important: join red to black.

**Summing amplifier**
You can use an opamp summing amplifier. Depending on the impedance of the microphone, you may need to buffer the microphone with high impedance buffer amplifiers to improve sensitivity, bandwidth, and noise (s/n is improved by using a high input impedance amplifier). Generally, piezo electric elements are fairly high impedance in the audio region.